# Data Storage Options in j2me

Tags: java, java-me

I am creating application in j2me. There is a huge data with whom I have to deal.
I have used RMS but speed of retrieving a data from RMS is tedious process. It takes long time then normal speed. 
I can't use File because it requires permission every time whenever I fetch data or store data.

so is there any other options for storing large data in j2me.

Thank you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

```
  Some third party database available for j2me application. See this link for list of database.
```

2.

```
  Store the data into text files and store the text files into your project workspace. You can read the data from this text files.
```

3.

```
  Finally you can store the data into server and fetch the data from server using webservice. But needs GPRS.
```

I preferred last point for using huge data.

harsh

Answer (score 2):

1. Some third party database available for j2me application. See this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/230853/JME/Mobile/List-Database-ME) for list of database.
2. Store the data into text files and store the text files into your project workspace. You can read the data from this text files.
3. Finally you can store the data into server and fetch the data from server using webservice. But needs GPRS.

I preferred last point for using huge data.